# Combine multiple number values into a total

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, numbers, addition

Trying to combine the number values from multiple divs.

Sometimes the amount of divs can be 1 and sometimes the amount of divs could be 500.

Trying to find a way to combine all of the number values into an out-put of a "combined total"

```js
function addNums() {
    var sum = ('.item-price' + '.item-price');
}

document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = addNums;
```

```html
<div class="item-price">$84</div>
<div class="item-price">$8</div>
<div class="item-price">$14</div>
<div class="item-price">$66</div>
<div class="item-price">$22</div>
<div class="item-price">$34</div>
<div class="item-price">$16</div>
<div class="item-price">$6</div>
<div class="item-price">$14</div>

<div class="item-total">Total:
  <span id="total" class="total" ></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the numbers from the tags and add to each other with reduce.

- `Array.from` makes a normal array from the DOM array
- Then we bring all texts inside the tags, remove the dollar sign and make them a number
- And finally, add them together with reduce.

```js
const items = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("item-price")).map(item => +item.innerText.substr(1));

document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = items.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
```

```html
<div class="item-price">$84</div>
<div class="item-price">$8</div>
<div class="item-price">$14</div>
<div class="item-price">$66</div>
<div class="item-price">$22</div>
<div class="item-price">$34</div>
<div class="item-price">$16</div>
<div class="item-price">$6</div>
<div class="item-price">$14</div>

<div class="item-total">Total:
  <span id="total" class="total" ></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the price in a variable (`total`). Select all the prices with `document.querySelectorAll('.item-price')`, loop through each with `forEach` and parse the price with `parseInt(element.innerHTML.substring(1)`, then add this to the total.

```js
function addNums() {
  var total = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('.item-price').forEach(e => total += parseInt(e.innerHTML.substring(1)));
  return total;
}

document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = addNums();
```

```html
<div class="item-price">$84</div>
<div class="item-price">$8</div>
<div class="item-price">$14</div>
<div class="item-price">$66</div>
<div class="item-price">$22</div>
<div class="item-price">$34</div>
<div class="item-price">$16</div>
<div class="item-price">$6</div>
<div class="item-price">$14</div>

<div class="item-total">Total:
  <span id="total" class="total"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addNums() {
 let prices = document.getElementsByClassName('item-price');
 let sum = 0;
 for(let  i = 0; i < prices.length;i++){
     let p = prices[i].innerText
     p = p.substring(1)
     sum = sum+parseInt(p)
  }
  
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum;
    
}

addNums();
```

```html
<div class="item-price">$84</div>
<div class="item-price">$8</div>
<div class="item-price">$14</div>
<div class="item-price">$66</div>
<div class="item-price">$22</div>
<div class="item-price">$34</div>
<div class="item-price">$16</div>
<div class="item-price">$6</div>
<div class="item-price">$14</div>

<div class="item-total">Total:
  <span id="total" class="total" ></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your JS code to this:

```js
function addNums() {
    var sum = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.item-price')).reduce((cum,x) => {
     return cum + parseInt(x.innerText.slice(1));
    },0);
    return '$' + sum;
}

document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = addNums();
```

```html
<div class="item-price">$84</div>
<div class="item-price">$8</div>
<div class="item-price">$14</div>
<div class="item-price">$66</div>
<div class="item-price">$22</div>
<div class="item-price">$34</div>
<div class="item-price">$16</div>
<div class="item-price">$6</div>
<div class="item-price">$14</div>

<div class="item-total">Total:
  <span id="total" class="total" ></span>
</div>
```

1. Get all `.item-price div`s using `querySelectorAll`. This returns a collection **not** an array, so you convert the collection into an array using `Array.from()`
2. `reduce` is used to convert an array into a single consolidated value after some calculations on each array element starting with an initial value. Here we are starting with initial value 0 and adding the price of each item.
3. `slice()` is used to slice arrays/strings, we use slice(1) to get the price value from the first index (ignoring `$`). That will be a string so we convert using `parseInt()`.
4. We return the value.

Note: Simply doing `var x = addNums` means `x` now holds the function. `addNums()` executes the function and doing `var x = addNums()` means `x` now holds the value returned by `addNums` on execution.